# Sorting a dropdown list but including 'Other' as list item at the end of sorted list

Tags: sql

I want to sort a dropdown list but ensure the item *"Other"* is present in the end of the sorted `dropdownlist`. I have tried using Order by on the list excluding  *'Other'* from it and then using *'union'* to append *'other'* to the sorted result. But it doesnot work.

Comment: Duplicate many times over. Use a CASE statement in your ORDER BY.

Comment: When you put queries together using UNION, you only get a single ORDER BY at the end of the whole thing.  So you'll need something else, such as a SortOrder column (or a CASE statement) to put them in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, thanks to those who gave their valuable suggestions here. It was more of a SQL query construction doubt. The problem I was facing was I could not use UNION after ORDER BY in the query, the result of which was to be used to populate ASP.NET control dropdownlist. The simple solution I found was to add a new fake column assigned to ddlitem.value in SELECT statement and then ORDER BY that column. The trick was to assign ddlitem.value to 999 (or a big value) for (ddlitem.text - OTHER) so that it always ended up at the end when ORDER BY was carried out using that fake column.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information on the control you are using (trying updating your tags with your control set name!) it is not possible to give you a specific example of code to fix your problem. 
This is because there are multiple layers in which your drop down list data may be ordered; the control may be preserving your original order from the SQL data set, but it may not be. It could have a default setting to alphabetize the elements, etc...
I have successfully dealt with cases like this in the past in two ways:

1.It is often possible to add data elements individually to a drop down list in your control initialization code. Simply add 'Other' to the end of the list using code along the lines of

`ddlUnknownControl.Add(new ddlElement("Other")`

2.When you just have a specific way in which you would like some data to be ordered (usually more than a one off value), you can actually put a column in your table specifically to be used as an index for ordering the data. Be careful with this! It must be carefully maintained and then, in order to guarantee your order is preserved, you will want to pull your information into your drop down list as a set of label, value pairs and order within the control by the value (where the value is the index and the label is the text information).